# Retrieving multiple entities from EF with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web API 2 in combination with the Entity Framework. I want to retrieve multiple entities with a controller method. I extract the parameters from the request header. Then I convert it into an two-dimensional array which contains the name and the value. Then I want to get all matching entities from the db. I already tried it with the `SqlQuery()` method in combination with a parameter array, but that doesn't work either.

I get an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException`
>   The datareader is not compatible with the given value. A element of the type ('ADRESSE1') does not have a corresponding column in the data reader of the same name.

This is my model:

```
public partial class ADRESSE
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ADRESSE1 { get; set; }
    public string PERSONAL { get; set; }
    public string LIEFERADR { get; set; }
    public string RECHNUNGADR { get; set; }
    public string FIRMA { get; set; }
    public string FIRMA1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This is the table in the database. (Because of the project client I can't change any naming in the db)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADRESSE]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ADRESSE] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [PERSONAL] [nvarchar](31) NULL,
    [LIEFERADR] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [RECHNUNGADR] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [FIRMA] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [FIRMA1] [nvarchar](63) NULL,
    ...
)
```

My query:

```
[HttpGet]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "HEAD")]
public IQueryable<ADRESSE> GetADRESSE()
{
   var header = HeaderExtractionProvider.GetRequestHeaders(Request.Headers);
   if (header.Count > 0)
   {
      var paramArray = new List<SqlParameter>();
      foreach (var param in header)
      {
         paramArray.Add(new SqlParameter(param[0], param[1]));
      }

      var test = db.ADRESSE.SqlQuery("Select * from ADRESSE", paramArray.ToArray());
      //return all found adresses here.
   }
   return db.ADRESSE;
}
```

Comment: share your query as well.

Comment: i added the query

Comment: Why you did not use Linq  to Entities ?

Comment: I found no query where I could insert a dynamical amount of parameters

Comment: provide your sql query including your `where clause `

Answer (score 1):

The database error that you're getting is because your property name `ADRESSE1` differs from your database column of `ADRESSE`. It doesn't know how to map that.

You can fix the issue with Entity Framework by using the [`ColumnAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) found in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`.

```
public partial class ADRESSE
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column("ADRESSE")]
    public string ADRESSE1 { get; set; }
    public string PERSONAL { get; set; }
    public string LIEFERADR { get; set; }
    public string RECHNUNGADR { get; set; }
    public string FIRMA { get; set; }
    public string FIRMA1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can then create a LINQ query like this:

```
var addresses = db.Addresses.Where(ad => paramArray.Contains(ad.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Query as follows with `Linq`

```
  var addressed = db.Addresses.Where(ad => paramArray.Contains(ad.Id));
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It highlights Where and select address and says sit isn't recognized.